# forge disconnected viewing demo

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit

Hi is anybody  can helps me?

i'm trying the disconnected viewing demo of **autodesk forge** but i have an issue.

i made a debugger to lunch the server on **localhost:3000**

```
    {
      // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
            "env": {
                "FORGE_CLIENT_ID": "jhuJGACtNUeCv24C8a0dz0Jhyz5WyQ6t",
                "FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET": "uSNhnZnEeJRLmHYn",
                "FORGE_CALLBACK_URL": "http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth",
                "FORGE_BUCKET": "saif_2017-05-28"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

the problem is my brower send me "are you offline" when i try to load a model.

[image: Viewer capture]

Comment: I found it i ran the viewer **locally**, service worker don't detect that i'm **online** the thing is i have t **deploy** it before in a server (like **heroku**) first, then the **service worker** catch the model and keep it **viewable offline**. hope can this post help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. Judging from the last screenshot, it looks like there were issues with authenticating your requests to the Forge APIs. When running the code locally make sure that you include the `FORGE_CLIENT_ID`, `FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET` and `FORGE_BUCKET` env. variables.